# Google sign in using firebase not working in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I saw a Youtube video to implement Google sign-in and below is the code. the app runs without any errors but when I click on the button, it shows the snack bar but nothing happens. the app is linked with firebase and Google sign-in is enabled

the code:

```
import 'package:app/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class GoogleSignin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleSigninState createState() => _GoogleSigninState();
}

class _GoogleSigninState extends State<GoogleSignin> {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn= new GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async{

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('Sign in'),
    ));

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser= await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth= await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential= GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);

    FirebaseUser userDetails= (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)) as FirebaseUser;
    ProviderDetails providerInfo= new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

    List<ProviderDetails> providerData=new List<ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details=new UserDetails(userDetails.photoUrl, providerData, userDetails.providerId, userDetails.email, userDetails.displayName);
    
    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> new HomePage()));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Image.asset('',fit: BoxFit.fill,),
              color: Color(0xFF080e44),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  width: 250.0,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Signin with Google', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF080e44),fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),)
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: ()=> _signIn(context)
                                        .then((FirebaseUser  user) => print(user))
                                        .catchError((e)=> print(e)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 250.0,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Signin with Email', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF080e44),fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),)
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 250.0,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Signin with Apple', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF080e44),fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),)
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserDetails{
  final String providerDetails;
  final String userName;
  final String photUrl;
  final String userEmail;
  final List<ProviderDetails> providerData;

  UserDetails(
      this.photUrl,
      this.providerData,
      this.providerDetails,
      this.userEmail,
      this.userName,
      );
}

class ProviderDetails{
  ProviderDetails(
      this.providerDetails
      );
  final String providerDetails;
}
```

Here's the **RUN log**:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device POCO F1...
Restarted application in 9,717ms.
I/flutter (22152): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (22152): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (22152): Unable to load asset:
I/flutter (22152): 
I/flutter (22152): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (22152): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (22152): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (22152): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:664:31)
I/flutter (22152): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:648:14)
I/flutter (22152): #3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
I/flutter (22152): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:359:22)
I/flutter (22152): #5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:499:80)
I/flutter (22152): #6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106:19)
I/flutter (22152): #7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:9)
I/flutter (22152): #8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:460:26)
I/flutter (22152): (elided 13 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (22152): 
I/flutter (22152): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "")
I/flutter (22152): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#80b2d(), name: "", scale: 1.0)
I/flutter (22152): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: 

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:664:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:648:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#80b2d(), name: "", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/om.app.constel(22152): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
W/om.app.constel(22152): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 175 to 100
I/om.app.constel(22152): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on ProfileSaver for 24.943ms
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/chatty  (22152): uid=10413(com.app.constell) Thread-4 identical 4 lines
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/chatty  (22152): uid=10413(com.app.constell) Thread-4 identical 3 lines
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
```

Any idea what this error means??

```
I/flutter (22152): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_s
```

........................................................................................................

Comment: Why is `asset path` blank here `Image.asset('',fit: BoxFit.fill,)` ?

Comment: i haven't designed the background yet. is that the reason this is happening??

Comment: yes, give some image there for now

Comment: just did. still the same problem :(

Comment: Updated in all places ? `pubspec.yaml` and the `dir` in your project ? Ran `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: To simplify for now you can use `Image.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg',fit: BoxFit.fill,)`